# Getting TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len() when using Input Text keyword robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Getting TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()  when using Input Text keyword robotframework

```
Input Text  id_q  searchvalue
```

Text box is visible and found using id_q. But still getting the error.

```
Output:
17:51:57.077    INFO    Typing text '45399135' into text field '//input[@id='id_q']'    
17:51:57.277    FAIL    TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()
```

Below is the stacktrace when run with -L Debug

```
18:41:22.896    INFO    Typing text '45398988' into text field  '//input[@id='id_q']'   
18:41:22.896    DEBUG   POST http://127.0.0.1:59465/hub/session/964cb9df-6090-40b3-bb4c-a1e79eab290c/elements {"using": "xpath", "sessionId": "964cb9df-6090-40b3-bb4c-a1e79eab290c", "value": "//input[@id='id_q']"}   
18:41:22.916    DEBUG   Finished Request    
18:41:22.926    DEBUG   POST http://127.0.0.1:59465/hub/session/964cb9df-6090-40b3-bb4c-a1e79eab290c/element/{931d6a04-99cf-4b26-9a45-b541011de684}/clear {"sessionId": "964cb9df-6090-40b3-bb4c-a1e79eab290c", "id": "{931d6a04-99cf-4b26-9a45-b541011de684}"}     
18:41:22.986    DEBUG   Finished Request    
18:41:23.116    FAIL    TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()   
18:41:23.116    DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in input_text
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_selenium2library-1.6.0-py2.7.egg\Selenium2Library\keywords\keywordgroup.py", line 12, in _run_on_failure_decorator
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_selenium2library-1.6.0-py2.7.egg\Selenium2Library\keywords\_formelement.py", line 198, in input_text
self._input_text_into_text_field(locator, text)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_selenium2library-1.6.0-py2.7.egg\Selenium2Library\keywords\_formelement.py", line 363, in _input_text_into_text_field
element.send_keys(text)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 316, in send_keys
for i in range(len(val)):
```

Comment: This is hard to debug without a stack trace. You need to run pybot with "-L DEBUG" parameter and then log.html should have stack trace. Include that here, it might point us to right direction.

Comment: @Pekka, Please see stacktrace copied above

Comment: Hi Madhu. This goes over my head. My only guess is that maybe somehow 45399135 is converted to long type before Input Text line. You could try to convert it back to string by adding this line before Input Text: ${searchvalue str}=    Convert To String    ${searchvalue}. Then change Input Text line to use ${searchvalue str}

Comment: It works after using Convert To String. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
for i in range(len(str(val)))
```